# Why is this React/Javascript object undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

So I'm trying to make this JSON into JavaScript objects but everything I've tried it's come up undefined. The objects do not work. I have some code here which is the `getStaticProps` method getting objects from my json file

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const json = await fetch(" /* LINK */ ");
  const properties = await json.json();
  const { starDesc, planetDesc, moonDesc, objectDesc } = properties;

  return {
    props: {
      starDesc,
      planetDesc,
      moonDesc,
      objectDesc,
    }
  };
}
```

And here's the overall structure of my json file ...

```
{
    "starDesc": {
        "starProperties": [{
                "name": "Spectral Type",
                "desc": "The spectral designation of a star."
            },
            {
                "name": "Color",
                "desc": "The color of a star's light. Bluer stars are usually hotter while redder stars are cooler."
            },

        ....

        ]
    },
    "planetDesc": {

        ....

    }
```

and so on

It's basically just saying all of those objects (`starDesc`, `planetDesc`, `moonDesc`, `objectDesc`) are undefined when they should be new javascript objects right? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here and any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Edit: Here's the export function. Just a simple test to get something to show up, but it's saying that `starDesc.starProperties` is undefined

```
export default function PropertySection(props) {
  return (

    <p>{props.starDesc.starProperties[0].name}</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: Show the `getStaticPath()`

Comment: `props: { starDesc, planetDesc, moonDesc, objectDesc, }`  Exactly what is this? It's not really an object, nor is it an array.  Did you try `props: [...]` ?   oops, Ben, right you are, my bad!

Comment: @zipzit it is an object, shorthand equivalent to `props: { starDesc: starDesc, planetDesc: planetDesc, ... }`

Comment: What does `console.log(json)` & `console.log(properties)` give? It seems more likely a problem with the data you're fetching.

Comment: There is no `getStaticPath()` because I don't need it for this but basically it's just giving me an error that the starDesc, planetDesc, etc is undefined

Comment: This might seem like a simple fix, but please give this a try. Replace the {} with () as shown:

```
return (
    props: {
      starDesc,
      planetDesc,
      moonDesc,
      objectDesc,
    }
  );
```

Comment: @Shah I just tried that and it's saying Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files. To be honest I've never used typescript before so I don't really know how it works

Comment: @joerup2004 I wonder if it would work if your JSON file had the keys not defined as strings.

Like what if it was:
```
{
    starDesc: {

        ....

    },
    planetDesc: {

        ....

    }
```

Because I'm wondering about the limitations of destructing objects in JS. Does it know if the key,  starDesc, is the same as the key as a string, "starDesc".

Comment: @Shah I could be wrong but I didn't think you could do that? I thought it had to be strings

Comment: I just know that if you have an object that looks like this:

const myObj = { 
    id: 1234, 
    name: "foo", 
} 

You could destructure with:

const { id, name } = myObj

But I wonder if it would work if myObj had the keys created as strings. I'm going to go try it out.

EDIT:

Yeah, it works the same... 

Does your getStaticProps return undefined or an empty object?

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. I just tried converting everything into arrays so it's in the format of `starDesc: [ [], [], [] ], planetDesc: [ [], [], [] ] ... ... ` but that still is not working ... so idk at this point

Comment: I'm just wondering if your request was fulfilled. If you console.log(properties) does it have the expected output? It seems like you're trying to use nextjs. I'm on the docs and your code looks correct to me.

Comment: Show the export default function.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the whole `getStaticProps()` isn't even being called since nothing is being printed to the console. What exactly causes the function to be called?

Comment: @itachi The export default function doesn't really have much yet, the only thing is it's supposed to return the `props.starDesc.starProperties[0].name` to test and it says that `props.starDesc` is undefined.

Comment: I should also mention this whole thing is a React component technically, so the whole view is being used as like `<PropertySection type="" sectionName=""/>`. Don't know if that makes a difference but figured I would mention it

Comment: Just show how you are passing the props and calling it. The code inside doesn't matter.

Comment: getStaticProps is called with every request in development.

Comment: `console.log(properties)` in `getStaticProps` will not show in the browser's console. `getStaticProps` happens on the server, you'll see your log in the terminal you started the server. There must be something wrong fetching the data.

Comment: @itachi I just added the export function to the main post.

Comment: @juliomalves Gotcha, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to get it to work. I believe the problem was that there were props being obtained from the html tag for the object, and additional props tags in the `getStaticProps` function, so I'm assuming these were conflicting. I ended up fetching the JSON data from a separate page which contains the `<PropertySection>` tag and just passed the JSON data into it from there. It now works. Thank you all for helping